# defining every image file from a folder as an ImageTk object flexibly

Tags: python, tkinter, directory

I am building a simple image viewer for tkinter practice.

I want to write a loop that will, for every image file in a folder, define a variable using the `ImageTk.PhotoImage()` method, then add it to a list.

To clarify, where the file names in the folder may have all sorts of names, the end result inside my script should look something like:

```
image_list = [image_0, image_1, image_2]
```

I've decided to go the route of using f string literals and `eval/exec()`. It hasn't worked with a couple hours of debugging.

This is what I have so far:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os

root = Tk()

image_list = []
images = os.listdir('folderpath')

for x in range(len(images)):
    eval(f'my_image_{x} = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("folderpath/{images[x]}"))')
    eval(f'image_list.append(my_image_{x}')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't just use `image_list = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join("folderpath", img)) for img in images]`.

Comment: What would they each be named in the list using list comprehension??

Comment: I don't understand why their names matter if they can be accessed using `image_list[0]`, `image_list[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

*Why* do you want `image_list` to contain variables `image_0`, `image_1`, etc. - which you are attempting to create dynamically; instead of the names of the files? How would you later reference those created variables? By generated the entire sequence and checking which exist in the local namespace? Also, a list can't contain a variable. When we define a list when variables, the value/object it points to is what gets added to the list.

You should instead create a dictionary of these names which point to each file/loaded image.

In any case, if you *really* did want to create the `image_0`, `image_1`, etc. variables in the local namespace, you can create a dictionary of the variables and their intended values and then update `locals()`:

```py
pre = 'my_image_'  # prefix. code uses 'my_image_', question uses 'image_'
for x, file in enumerate(images):  # gives index and filename
    d = {f'{pre}{x}': ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f'folderpath/{file}'))}
    locals().update(d)  # so now you can do `my_image_0` etc. in code
    image_list.append(eval(f'{pre}{x}'))  # adds the image to the list, it's not a list of variables
```

Instead of all that, what you *should* do is:

```py
pre = 'my_image_'
image_dict = {}
for x, file in enumerate(images):
    image_dict[f'{pre}{x}'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f'folderpath/{file}'))
    image_list.append(f'{pre}{x}')  # list of names as strings; but unnecessary
```

And then to iterate over your images, since Python3.6 onwards, dictionary items are provided in the same order as insertion:

```py
for image_name, image in image_dict.items():
    print(image_name)
    panel = Label(root, image=image)
    ...  # and other code to display your image
```

So you don't need `image_list`. But if you did want to use it, for example, to display the last image:

```py
image_name = image_list[-1]
image = image_dict[image_name]
print(image_name)
display(image)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hear you; Giving each image an arbitrary name in a list is pretty pointless.

I tried the dictionary method and it's become clear that the problem lays outside of the dict/list debate. here's what I'm getting:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latest test.py", line 14, in <module>
    image_dict[f'{pre}{x}'] = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f'{path}/{file}'))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2943, in open
    raise UnidentifiedImageError(
PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/Users/Trane/desktop/tkinter/Images/PythonBootcampCertificate.pdf'
(base) Bens-MacBook-Pro:tkinter Trane$

Comment: Well, that's because the file it's trying to parse as an image is a PDF: `PythonBootcampCertificate.pdf`. You can either limit to just image types (by checking the filename extension before trying to open it) or put that one line in a `try: <img load line> except UnidentifiedImageError: pass` block. See [Exception Handling](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).